# Ionic ion-datetime: how to set default picker value

Tags: javascript, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3, momentjs

I have the following need: the end-user should input a datetime in a field that is empty. Thanks to the business logic, this datetime can be suggested by the app. So what I would like to do is that clicking on the empty field displays the suggested datetime in both the field and the ion-datetime component.

Here is my code:

In HTML

```
    <ion-datetime   displayFormat='YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm' 
                    pickerFormat='YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
                    text-center 
                    (click)="init_worked_time()" 
                    [(ngModel)]='worked_time'>                  
    </ion-datetime>
```

In Typescript

```
init_worked_time() {
    if (this.worked_time == undefined) {
        if (this.times.start_time != 0) { 
            let tzoffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
            this.worked_time = moment(this.times.start_time).subtract(tzoffset, 'milliseconds').toISOString().slice(0, -1);
        } 
    }
}
```

The problem is that the suggested value is well displayed in the field after clicking on it but the ion-datetime component shows the current UTC time (even not local time…)

[image]

Is there any better approach for such need? Or maybe is there any possibility to update programmatically the displayed value of the ion-datetime component?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not completly sure, If I understood your problem. You want to fill in a suggested timestamp (date and time) into a ion-datetime component, when the user clicked onto it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. When opening the page, the field is empty, but clicking on it should fill the suggested datetime, and the end user can correct it if necessary. The problem is that updating the variable worked_time (on click event) does not update the ion-datetime's interface

Comment: hey! I added a pull request that may be helpful to your question here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/pull/24206

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You using momentJs which already by default use hte local time so there is no need to subtract the offset.

```
init_worked_time() {
    if (this.worked_time == undefined) {
        if (this.times.start_time != 0) { 
            this.worked_time = moment(this.times.start_time).format();
        } 
    }
}
```

In your HTML you need to use the event `tap` instead of `click`:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat='YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm' 
                    pickerFormat='YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'  (tap)="init_worked_time()"
                    text-center 
                    [ngModel]='worked_time'>                  
    </ion-datetime>
```

Here's an online **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-x3feyf)**

Comment: Ah thanks, good to know, this makes my code a bit shorter and cleaner :-) Nevertheless unfortunately this does not solve my problem: the datetime displayed in interface is not equal to the suggested value computed by the mobile app.

Comment: @Pierre what do you mean " the datetime displayed in interface is not equal to the suggested value "? Did the result not change? Is it still not displaying the local time?

Comment: Please see the picture above, I just updated it to make it more clear. The value displayed in the ion-datetime component is not equal to the computed this.worked_time.

Comment: @Pierre I see. You want to set a default value for datetime. Check the edit

Comment: Ohhh yes, this works very well, thanks a lot for your help!! Have a good day :-)